# How to calculate a linear regression with a predefined slope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am able to calculate the full linear regression using the `LinearRegression` class in scikit-learn:

```
XX=np.array(plotx_aj).reshape((-1, 1))
YY=np.array(ploty_aj)


model=LinearRegression().fit(XX,YY)
r_sq=model.score(XX,YY)
inter=model.intercept_
coeff=model.coef_
r_sq, i, coef
```

and this gives me the following plot

[image: Linear regression]

However, I am trying to fit a line with a fixed slope. I only need to calculate the intercept of the line.

The method i was thinking first about using is the following one:

- take all the points that describe the profiles of my object at other temperatures,
- then subtract their distance * slope
- This would kind of make a rotation of the picture and after that I would only have to take the mean of the points which would give me an approximation of the intercept.

I think my solution gives a good approximation but it is pretty nasty. That's why I am trying to approach the value of intercept with a regression type of method. I went through a lot of websites but they only describe how to do a linear regression on python but no one seems to talk about doing it with a fixed coefficient so I don't even really know if it's possible or if it makes sense.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please review my edits to your question. The background on how you got the data and what it describes is irrelevant to the problem you are asking about -- which is how to calculate a linear regression with a fixed slope. See [ask] -- you should focus your question to _just_ the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to compute the intercept for a fixed slope, you can pose this problem as a minimization problem on the [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) between the actual points and a function that describes a line with your known slope and a single variable: the intercept.

First, let's create a set of points with some noise around a known line equation: `y = 0.5 * x + 0.1`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def known_equation(x):
    # m = 0.5; c = 0.1
    return 0.5 * x + 0.1

def noise(y, n=0.05):
    return y + (np.random.random(y.shape) - 0.5) * n

xvals = np.random.random((100,))
yvals = noise(known_equation(xvals))

line_x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
line_y = known_equation(line_x)

plt.subplots()
plt.plot(xvals, yvals, '.')
plt.plot(line_x, line_y, '-k')
```

[image]

Next, let's write a function that calculates the sum of squared errors between the known points and a hypothetical line `y = m * x + c`:

```
def err_f(m, c, known_x, known_y):
    y_pred = m * known_x + c
    return ((known_y - y_pred)**2).sum()
```

Finally, let's run a minimization algorithm on this function. I use [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), but you can use anything else that you prefer. The `functools.partial` call fixes the known arguments to `err_f`: `m`, `known_x`, and `known_y`.

```
from functools import partial
from scipy.optimize import minimize

err_f_fixed = partial(err_f, 0.5, known_x=xvals, known_y=yvals)

# Make sure err_f_fixed is correct:
assert err_f(0.5, 0.1, xvals, yvals) == err_f_fixed(0.1)

opt_result = minimize(err_f_fixed, 0)

opt_intercept = opt_result.x[0] # Since this is an array, take its first element
```

We get `opt_intercept = 0.09903487233324053`, which is close enough to our known value of `0.1`!

When we plot this and compare the two lines, we see that they're nearly identical:

```
line_y_calculated = 0.5 * x_plot + opt_intercept

plt.plot(line_x, line_y_calculated, '--r')
```

[image]